# Maintain the order with searching

Tags: mysql

I have a table of location, that have more than 150 locations with area and zipcode columns. I am using query "Select area from locations where area like %n%", then i am getting results `Nigdi
Nigdi
Nigdi
Chinchwad
Chinchwad
Nasik`

Here why i am getting Nasik in last, even my first search keyword is 'n'. And Nasik has the 'n' at first location. Can Somebody help please.

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: after order by m not getting order that i want. Here i want Nasik, Nigdi Chinchwad. with group by also.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order by the position of "n" in the area, then you need to specify that.  Remember, a SQL query returns an *unordered* set unless you explicitly include `order by`.  So:

```
Select area
from locations
where area like '%n%'
order by instr(area, 'n'), area;
```

Comment: Fair enough, perhaps I closed too soon as it was unclear.  I would probably recommend adding `, area` to the end of the `order by` though.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but I'm guessin that you want one of the following:

```
SELECT area FROM locations WHERE area LIKE '%n%' ORDER BY area
```

or

```
SELECT area FROM locations WHERE area LIKE 'n%' ORDER BY area
```

Comment: i tried with your second query. bt in this m not getting Chinchwad area. I want like Nasik, Nigdi, Nigdi, Chinchwad. Hope you understand my question now